# Handle missing data in SQL Server 2012 SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

```
 create table t1 (col1 int);
```

Leave the table empty.

```
select isnull(col1,0) from t1;
```

I want to replace null with zeros in the above case. However, `ISNULL()` does not work if there are no records in the table.  How can I get around this?

Comment: It's totally unclear what you mean by *"...even isnull not work if there is no record in table or in selection criteria."* Maybe you could add an example of your data and the desired result.

Comment: ISNULL requires a value to operate against. AFAIK, you cannot tell SQL Server to create a dummy row to operate against.

Comment: Why has this been put on hold? The question couldn't be any clearer...

Comment: @RobbieDee And why has the user not accepted an answer or clarified?    I have an answer too.  But the question is dead.

Comment: Some users don't - especially new ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can first test if the table is empty:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from t1) 
    SELECT 0
ELSE select coalesce(col1,0) from t1;
```

Anyway, you should use COALESCE instead of ISNULL because it is standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to replace non existing value then surround another null check of mentioned select statement. like this

```
ISNULL(select isnull(col1,0) from t1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
COALESCE(col1, 0)
```

will give you the first non-NULL value from the list, which is

- `col1` if `col1` does not contain `NULL`
- `0` if `col1` contains `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If no record exists in the table , your query returns EMPTY not NULL .
You can transform the EMPTY value into a NULL value and then switch it to 0 like this :

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT col1 FROM tl),0) AS col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must have a value returned for an empty table, maybe something like:

```
if ((select COUNT(*) from t1) = 0)
begin
    select 0 as col1;
end
else
begin
    select isnull(col1,0) as col1 from t1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When I want to return *exactly* one row from a table that might be empty or have an arbitrary number of rows, then I often use aggregation:

```
select coalesce(max(col1), 0)
from t1;
```

This is guaranteed to return exactly one row.  It is unclear what you want when the table is not empty, however.

Answer (score 0):

The `left join` will get a hard coded table, `OneZero`, even with no rows in `t1`.

```
select isnull(t1.col1, OneZero.zero) 
from ( values(0) ) as OneZero (zero)
left join t1 
  on 1 = 1
```